# Geolocation using current location as variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, geolocation, currentlocation

I have adapted this code to try and get it to work for my situation. What I am attempting to do is find the visitors current location, and map directions to a certain location on load.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">  
</script>

<script>
  var directionsDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.3094610,-85.5791560)
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
    var control = document.getElementById('control');
    control.style.display = 'block';
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = 'current location';
    var end = ('38.3094610,-85.5791560');
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
     };

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
           directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
       }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

What I'm needing is to store the current location in a variable so I can use it in the
calcRoute function as start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, you should really try to demonstrate that you have made some effort to so solve the problem and researched it thoroughly. You can't just dump a load of code and expect people to fix it for you. See here for guidelines on asking good questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Not trying to be rude here but I said all that in my first line..

"I have adapted this code to try and get it to work for my situation"

Adapted meaning that I have altered/changed/tried to get it to work. Also, I have tried researching this, how do you think I came accross this site?

Comment: All questions from new users go through a review process to ensure they meet the guidelines mentioned above, and to make sure you are aware of their importance. In this case I felt that your question could be improved by some of the suggestions in that article. It is of course up to you if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First detect whether the browser supports geo tracking at all:

```
if (!window.navigator||
    !window.navigator.geolocation||
    !window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition) return;
```

Then build location handlers:

```
function geo_success(pos){
  var lat=pos.coords.latitude;
  var lng=pos.coords.longitude;

  //do your mapping magic here
}

function geo_error(pos){
  // do nothing
}
```

Now register the tracker:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    geo_success, geo_error, 
    {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:10000, timeout:10000});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get the gelocation from the browser?  If so, try [this article](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

TL;DR

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
```

where `callback` is a javascript function to call after the user's location has been determined.

Comment: I don't see in the code where it is obtained, and I have searched for examples on how to obtain them but I am having a hard time implementing them. Every change that I make results in a partial page load. This appears to be the easiest yet I can't implement it lol

    <code>var lat=pos.coords.latitude;
    var lng=pos.coords.longitude;</code>

@Mike